# installation tells "warning: "./..." matched no packages" under linux(ubuntu 14.04 64bit)

Tags: installation, nim-lang

I followed the steps within this page:

```
http://nim-lang.org/download.html
```

when run

```
cd csources && sh build.sh
```

I got this warning

```
~/projects/Nim$ cd csources && sh build.sh
   warning: "./..." matched no packages
   no packages to test
~/projects/Nim/csources$
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the kindly help from irc channel's @vegansk and @cheatfate , I finally identified the problem:
I have a customize command called "tr" too,after renaming it,compilation works now.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, same question with resolution here: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/3974